# Building Swift / ObjC regular expression

Tags: swift, nsregularexpression

In a text string, I am trying to fetch everything between

`[DATA FORMAT]` and `/DATA FORMAT]`

and

`Columns Format:` and `/DATA FORMAT]`

to this goal I use regular expressions.

While the pattern

`"\\[DATA FORMAT\\](.*?)\\[/DATA FORMAT\\]"`

works as expected, the pattern

`"Columns Format(*.?)\\[/DATA FORMAT\\]"`

gives an error

`Optional("The value “Columns Format(*.?)\\[/DATA FORMAT\\]” is invalid.")`
`The value “Columns Format(*.?)\[/DATA FORMAT\]” is invalid.`

printed in the console (first line: localizedFailureReason, second line:localizedDescription)

What did I miss ?

Code :

```
extension String
{
    func match (pattern: String,
                options: RegularExpression.Options = [.caseInsensitive, .dotMatchesLineSeparators]) -> [String]
    {
        do
        {
            let regex     = try RegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: options)
            let regexAnsw = regex.matches(in: self, options: RegularExpression.MatchingOptions.withTransparentBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count))

            var retStrings = [String]()

            for rs in regexAnsw
            {
                if let range = self.range(from: rs.range)
                {
                    retStrings.append(self.substring(with: range))
                }
                else
                {
                    print("match: cant' convert NSRange to range")
                }
            }

            return retStrings
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print(error.localizedFailureReason)
            print(error.localizedDescription)

            return [String]()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `*` and `.` swapped in the second regex (in the capture group right after "Column Format"). This makes the regex invalid; the `*` isn't referring to anything.

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much.